# Unity Dependency Injection and Helper functions

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a set of services that are used to read/write to the database. These get injected into my controllers:

```
ISystemSettingService _systemSettingService = null;
IStatusTypeService _statusTypeservice = null;

public MyController(
    ISystemSettingService systemSettingService,
    IStatusTypeService statusTypeservice)
{
    _systemSettingService = systemSettingService;
    _statusTypeservice = statusTypeservice;
}
```

So when I need something from `_systemSettingService` I can easily get it. Now I also have some static helper classes/functions which I call from `MyController`. In these functions I often need access to the services so I can access the DB. e.g. I have a `Validate(string userData, ISystemSettingService systemSettingService)` function that accepts some data passed in from the user.

So far, into the `Validate` function I have been passing in the `_systemSettingService` so I can use it. I'm not sure this is correct.

My question - is my approach correct or, in the `Validate` function should I be creating a unity container to `Resolve` an instance of my `ISystemSettingService` or, as I have been reading about, should my helper class NOT be static, and I should inject `ISystemSettingService` into the constructor which will apparently make unit testing easier.

I'm a bit confused! Thanks.